# Как отсортировать массив от большого к меньшему?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с информацией игрока и количеству убийств в строковом представлении: `"имя_игрока:количество_убийств"`

Как отсортировать такой массив от количества больших "убийств" к меньшему?

```
const playerKills = [
  "player1:1462", 
  "player2:6755", 
  "player3:17"
]

// Логика сортировки

console.log(playerKills)
/*
[
  "player2:6755", 
  "player1:1462",
  "player3:17"
]
*/
```

Comment: от большего ЧЕГО?

Comment: Фильтрация подразумевает уменьшение элементов... Ты же, скорее всего, спрашиваешь про сортировку...

Answer (score 1):

> как отфильтровать такой массив от большого к меньшему?

Скорее всего речь идет не о фильтрации, а о сортировке. Предложу такой вариант

```js
const a = ["player1:1462", "player2:6755", "player3:17"]
a.sort((a, b) => b.split(':')[1] - a.split(':')[1])
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки массива строк в порядке убывания (от большего к меньшему) на основе численных значений в каждой строке (количество убийств), вы можете использовать метод [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) с функцией сравнения. В данном случае, вам нужно разделить каждую строку по двоеточию, преобразовать в числа количество убийств и сравнить их для определения порядка сортировки.
Пример:

```
const playerKills = ["player1:1462", "player2:6755", "player3:17"];
playerKills.sort((a, b) => {
  // Разделяем строки по двоеточию и преобразуем количество убийств в числа
  const killsA = parseInt(a.split(":")[1]);
  const killsB = parseInt(b.split(":")[1]);

  // Сравниваем числа для сортировки в порядке убывания
  return killsB - killsA;
});
```

Этот код сначала разделяет каждую строку в массиве по двоеточию, преобразует количество убийств в числа и затем сравнивает их для сортировки массива в порядке убывания.

Comment: Спасибо вам, я понял смысл кода, благодарю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад был вам помочь разобраться в вопросе! ))